# Search index futures in Yahoo Finance or Google Finance

Tags: options, futures, yahoo-finance, google-finance

I was wondering if index futures and options information are available in Yahoo/Google Finance. Say futures/options for Dow Jones Industrial Average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Options** - yes we can :)

> Options tickers on Yahoo! Finance will be displayed as per new options
>   symbology announced by OCC.
>
> The basic parts of new option symbol are: Root symbol + Expiration
>   Year(yy)+ Expiration Month(mm)+ Expiration Day(dd) + Call/Put
>   Indicator (C or P) + Strike price

Ex.: AAPL January 19 2013, Put 615 would be AAPL130119P00615000

http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=AAPL130119P00615000&ql=1

**Futures** - yes as well (:

Ex.: 6A.M12.E would be 6AM12.CME using Yahoo Finance symbology. (simple as that, try it out)

Get your major futures symbols from here:

http://quotes.ino.com/exchanges/exchange.html?e=CME

Answer (score 3):

Neither site offers index futures or options pricing.  Your best best is likely to get the quote from a broker who supports trading those vehicles. Free sites usually limit themselves to stocks and sometimes to options chains -- the exception is Reuters where just about any security for which you have the reuters formatted trading symbol can be quoted.

Answer (score 2):

Yahoo finance does in fact have futures quotes.  But I've found them difficult to search for because you also have to know the expiration codes for the contract to find them.

[S&P 500 Emini quote for June 2012](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=SPM12.CME)